# Child form goes inside the parent form bounds?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created the custom form and I have created the mdi child for the form. While the parent form is maximized,the child form bounds moves inside the parent form. I have tried with the following code in the `OnWmNcCalcSize()` method and it works fine on my screen. On my secondary monitor it does not working properly. `RC.left` is getting some other value. So Can I get any suggestions to fix this issue?[image]

```
                rc.top += fl.CaptionHeight;
                if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
                {
                    ///<summary>
                    /// local variable to store x-coordinate of native rectangle,rc.left is -6 when we double click on title-bar and -8 when we click the maximize button.
                    /////</summary>
                    int xcoordinate = rc.left;
                    rc.left -= xcoordinate;
                    rc.right += xcoordinate;
                    rc.bottom += xcoordinate;
                }
```

Comment: Are your monitors with the same resolutions and if not are you considering which monitor the window is in?

Comment: The resolutions are not same for the monitors and I don't know how to find the monitor in which the window is in. Is there any generic way to resolve this in all monitors?